# Editar pág ASP.NET compilada

Tags: asp.net, aplicação-web, visual-studio-2013, dll

Bom dia,

Tenho uma aplicação WEB pronta e preciso dar manutenção nela, alterar umas tabelas que são referenciadas nela e etc.

Porém não possuo o projeto, apenas a página compilada com os arquivos em aspx, o Web Config e os DLL.

Existe alguma forma de reverter para projeto para conseguir editar?
Ou precisarei começar do zero?

A aplicação não utiliza nenhum framework.

Obrigada.

Comment: Se vc não tem o projeto com suas classes você vai precisar criar do zero, você até pode reverter , mas no final é melhor vc ter um novo projeto ja que vai ficar dando manutenção, certamente o projeto e de terceiros por isso vc só tem as dll.

Answer (score 0):

Tente com um decompiler para reverter a compilação do código como o https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/, isto permitirá visualizar as classes das dll's caso não tenham sido intencionalmente embaralhadas/criptografadas, mas ainda assim terá que resolver as dependências externas se houver.